# Is it possible to prevent an android from slowing down in just 2 or 3 years or even 4 years

Tags: performance, android-versions, clock-speed

I know that SSDs wear out with time but it takes a long amount of time for the wear out noticeable affect performance (not 2 or three years). I can TRIM the SSD as far as I know to bring back it's old performance. I believe that RAM and CPUs/GPUs don't slow down with time (not 2 years that is usually the amount of time after which people start feeling like they need a new phone). So is it possible for a phone to be as fast as it was 2 years ago if the apps in the current age are also not more CPU demanding than they were 2 years ago?
PS. also my last question is unanswered so please consider replying to that

Comment: I used a Samsung Galaxy Y Duos GT-S6102 with 160 MB storage / 290 MB RAM for many years, i really liked it because of its size. finally google maps stopped working (Android 2.3.6) it became useless because of lack of support, hardware still works fine

Comment: If the SSD is overused the flash cells itself are getting slower, therefore TRIMMing will not help in this case. But if you are afraid of SSD degration you can simply buy a phone with double the memory you need and leave the half unused. Anyway AFAIK a flash degration is today not very likely unlesss you don't write every day hundret of GB to it.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant. People buy a new phone saying that their phone has got slower but I have always wondered if it had actually or it's just the current version of the apps they that demand more than the phone can give. If the apps weren't updated ever, I think everything would have been fine. Or people can just factory reset and run TRIM because that will bring back factory verison of all apps